# Characterizing invertibility of time series by natural filtrations

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, time-series

I'm studying linear time series and I'm thinking whether is possible to characterize an **invertible moving average** of order q (i.e.: MA(q) ) by means of filtrations generated by the two processes. More formally let

$$Y_t = \epsilon_t + \theta_1 \epsilon_{t-1}+\theta_2 \epsilon_{t-2} + ...+\theta_q \epsilon_{t-q}$$

where $(\epsilon_t)_{t \in N}$ and $(Y_t)_{t \in N}$ are both discrete time stochastic processes.

**Can we state that:**

$(Y_t)_{t \in N}$ invertible if and only if the filtration generated by the two processes at a fixed time $t$ are equal? More formally:

$$(Y_t)_{t \in N} \ invertible \iff F^Y_t=F^{\epsilon}_t  \quad \forall t \in N$$

For $F_t^Y$ natural filtration of the process $(Y_t)_{t \in N}$ up to time $t$ (and same for $\epsilon$).

Sufficiency ($\Rightarrow$) seems to me pretty trivial consequence of basic measure theory. But I really have no clue about how to prove or disprove the necessity part.